# Html/Css expanding menu, how?

Tags: html, css, menubar

So, what I want to make is simple, I want an expanding menu. So for example, if you hover or click over/on one item, like "Home", there will appear several other items underneath it.

Basically, what I want is a floating div underneath the menu item. I already tried

```
menubar {
visibility:hidden
}

menubar:hover, menubar:active {
visibility:visible
}
```

This doesn't work!

Help? Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: Apologies, I'm fairly new to this site. I thought I explained it enough, but well, here you go :)

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346714/how-to-add-another-sub-menu-for-my-table/21351796#comment32206881_21351796

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find it in the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/d74Yv/

Basically we're using `:hover` and `+` selectors to show the submenu only when either its `.handler` or the `.menu` itself is hovered.